# Why is my Google Books API example failing?

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client, google-books

I'm using the Google Books php api example and I'm not getting any results of the call.

Here's an example of what I get when I run

examples/simple-query.php

[image: Simple API Access results]

It seems be looking up "Henry David Thoreau" but the results, as you can see, come back blank!

I set up and entered my API key as requested, but I don't seem to be getting anything, hmm.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the example is outdated, I got some 'undefined index' errors (your PHP installation is probably [not showing notices](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php), that's why it's blank).

You can fix the example source replacing this:

```
foreach ($results as $item) {
  echo $item['volumeInfo']['title'], "<br /> \n";
}
```

with:

```
foreach ($results->getItems() as $item) {
  echo $item->volumeInfo->getTitle(), "<br /> \n";
}
```

Comment: Ahh, they're JSON instead of arrays? That makes a lot of sense. Thanks a lot!